# Trying to copy over formatting from a Google Sheet to a Google Slide

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

As the title insinuates, I am trying to include a code block in my apps script that will allow me to copy over data from a Google Sheet to a Google Slide. Formatting as in column and row widths, font colors, font sizes, font styles, etc. Below is my script so far:

```
const PRESENTATION_ID = '1ZAFsD1pLRXYyj-623kAIwHQ6CK77vaT3Y4pMMDgLyDo';
const SHEET_ID = "1JjDBJ-opX6AHL17zGkGV9ZugvZ0Pf-MwaEeLQYkM2aQ";

// Master function; all others below pull in "sections" of data to be used in the master function.
function generatePresentationData() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID);
  let spendData = getDataFromSheet_(sheet);
  let slides = getSlides_();
  writeDataToPlayersSlide_(slides, spendData);
  setTableFormatting_(slides);
}

// This function pulls in data from the spreadsheet.
function getDataFromSheet_(sheet) {
  let dataRange = sheet.getRange('A2:L14');
  let data = dataRange.getValues();
  data.shift();
  return data;  
}

// This function identifies the slides for the data to be written to.
function getSlides_() {
  let presentation = SlidesApp.openById(PRESENTATION_ID);
  let slides = presentation.getSlides();
  return slides;
}

// This function writes the data into the slide.
function writeDataToPlayersSlide_(slides, spendData) {
  let slidePlayers = slides[0];

  for(let i = 0; i < spendData.length; i++) {
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{name${i}}}`, spendData[i][0]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{ytd1_${i}}}`, spendData[i][1]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{bud1_${i}}}`, spendData[i][2]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{rr1_${i}}}`, spendData[i][3]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{ytd2_${i}}}`, spendData[i][5]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{bud2_${i}}}`, spendData[i][6]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{rr2_${i}}}`, spendData[i][7]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{ytd3_${i}}}`, spendData[i][9]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{bud3_${i}}}`, spendData[i][10]);
    slidePlayers.replaceAllText(`{{rr3_${i}}}`, spendData[i][11]);
  }
}

function getTableFormatting_() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getRange('A2:L14');
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  const fontWeights = range.getFontWeights();
  const fontColors = range.getFontColorObjects();
  const fontFamilies = range.getFontFamilies();
  const fontLines = range.getFontLines();
  const fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();
  const horizAlign = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
  const vertAlign = range.getVerticalAlignments();
  const numFormat = range.getNumberFormats();
  const fontWrap = range.getWraps();
}

function setTableFormatting_(getTableFormatting_) {
  
  writeDataToPlayersSlide_.setBackgrounds(backgrounds).setFontWeights(fontWeights).setFontColors(fontColors).setFontFamilies(fontFamilies).setFontLines(fontLines).setFontSizes(fontSizes).setHorizontalAlignments(horizAlign).setVerticalAlignments(vertAlign).setNumberFormats(numFormat).setWraps(fontWrap);
}
```

Here are links to my source sheet and slides (make a copy if you want to use them)

Slides: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ZAFsD1pLRXYyj-623kAIwHQ6CK77vaT3Y4pMMDgLyDo/edit#slide=id.p

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JjDBJ-opX6AHL17zGkGV9ZugvZ0Pf-MwaEeLQYkM2aQ/edit#gid=0

I figured for the formatting piece I would have to "pull in" the formatting from the sheet which is what the getTableFormatting function is doing. I am lost on how to "set" the formatting to the slide though. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, unfortunately, it seems that your provided samples cannot be opened.